# Подсчитать количество столбцов, не содержащих ни одного нулевого элемента

Tags: php

**Подсчитать количество столбцов, не содержащих ни одного нулевого элемента**

Вот со строками у меня получилось, а как такое провернуть со столбцами?

```
function GetCounterOfRowsWithoutZeroFromMatrix($matrix) {
    $counter = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++) {
        $hasZero = false;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($matrix[$i]); $j++)
            if($matrix[$i][$j] == 0) {
                $hasZero = true;
                break;
            }
        if(!$hasZero)
            $counter++;
    }
    return $counter;
}
```

Теперь надо придумать метод GetCounterOfColumnsWithoutZeroFromMatrix.
Хелп)

Answer (score 0):

```php
function GetCounterOfColumnsWithoutZeroFromMatrix($matrix){
    $result = array();
    foreach($matrix as $key=>$row){
        $result = array_merge( array_keys( $row, 0, true ), $result);
    }
    return count(array_unique($result));
}
```